# Accessing Message Body in Azure DevOps Runs API

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, webhooks, azure-pipelines-yaml

I am trying to trigger my Azure Pipeline using an HTTP request. I am doing this using the Runs API provided by Azure DevOps,
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run-pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0

I want to be able to access the message body sent along with the POST request, within my pipeline.

I know that it is possible to do the following,

Add parameters to my pipeline similar to what has been shown below,

```
parameters:
   - name: id
     type: string
```

Send the message body of my request to the Runs API within `templateParameters` to be able to access the values as parameters.

The issue that I am facing is, my pipeline will actually be triggered by a Webhook and as a result, I don't have control over the structure of the message body. I cannot put the data within `templateParameters` for the values to be accessible through the parameters.

Is there any other way that I can access the values of the message body? Is there some other solution to my problem?

Comment: The Webhook that will trigger your pipeline will have to send a body as defined in the devops API. Ii is not a `freestyle` body. So yeah defining parameters in YAML is the way to go. You just need to let people knows what are the parameters that are required to trigger your pipeline.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As @Thomas mentioned, the body of the request sent will need to be as defined in the DevOps API, therefore, I had to use an Azure Function as an intermediary to take my initial request, put it inside of `templateParameters` and re-route it to Azure DevOps.